# PasswordBroker.php line 238 laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, reset-password

I'm trying to do the Authentication in my project laravel 5.2 the problem is I need to change the tables names because I have many projects in the same database.

I changed the name on users and password_resets tables in the following life:

- \migrations....create_password_resets_table.php
- \migrations....create_user_table.php
- in \app\User.php i added protected $table = 'r_users';
- in \Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php i changed 'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:r_users',
- in \config\auth.php i put:

  'providers' => [
           'users' => [
               'driver' => 'database',
               'table' => 'r_users',
           ],
      ],

  and

  'passwords' => [
          'users' => [
              'provider' => 'users',
              'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
              'table' => 'r_password_resets',
              'expire' => 60,
          ],

With these changes I can add new user in the new tables and I can do the login and logout.

But when I try to password reset I get that error. Any idea to fix this problem?

I assume there are other variables that I need to change but I don't know which.

I did the test before change the tables names and it working.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the attribute `prefix` in the `config/database.php`. you just need to set a different prefix for every project.

`.env`

```
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=pfx
```

`config/database.php`

```
'prefix' => env('DB_TABLE_PREFIX', '')
```